# TFS getcs doesn't delete local files when a file was deleted in the changeset?

Tags: tfs

Using TFS. I have a specific changeset where I delete a file. I use the `powertools getcs` on that changeset, I saw "`Deleting $/dir/my_file`" at the console, but my file still there on my filesystem. There is a way to perform the local delete when I get a changeset that have a delete?

I also notice the same when I perform a 'Get Latest Version'

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which type of workspace you are using, local or server, also if you have the file checked out / read only removed. If the file is 'checked out' then it won't be overwritten, even for delete, as the file is classed as 'pending change' and you maybe preparing to reintroduce the file to the code base. Based on that statement though you should receive a merge warning

Housekeeping should be done regularly. Delete the files in your local file system, then goto source control advanced and do a get specific version, tick both boxes and click get. This will refresh your workspace with the latest version of your code base